# Erro ao executar o SUM - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, query

Galera, estou tentando realizar o SUM conforme a consulta abaixo, porém, ocorre o seguinte erro. "Não é possível executar uma função de agregação em uma expressão que contenha uma agregação ou uma subconsulta." A saída é para sair dessa forma.

```
Total_Horas   MesID        Mes     Ano
60             1         Janeiro   2018
```

Consulta

```
select 
sum(dbo.FN_CALC_HORAS_UTEIS(s.SolData,min(l.LogData))),datepart(month,s.SolData) MesID,datename(month,s.soldata) Mes,datepart(year,s.soldata) Ano
from 
Solicitacao S
left join usuario U 
on (U.UsuID = S.UsuIDResponsavel) 
left join Status ST
on S.SolStatus = ST.CodStatus
left join Log L on L.LogSolID = s.SolID and (l.LOGDESCRICAO like '%1057%' or l.LOGDESCRICAO like '%3343%')
where S.proid in (2) and S.UsuIDResponsavel in(1776) and s.SolStatus <> 9 and convert(date,s.soldata) between '01-01-2018' and getdate()--and s.SolID = 65513
group by datepart(month,s.SolData),datename(month,s.soldata) ,datepart(year,s.soldata)
```

Answer (score -1):

Tente assim, com uma query externa:

```
select
    *,
    sum(horas_uteis) as soma_horas
from (
    select
        dbo.FN_CALC_HORAS_UTEIS(s.SolData,min(l.LogData)) as horas_uteis
        datepart(month,s.SolData) MesID,
        datename(month,s.soldata) Mes,
        datepart(year,s.soldata) Ano
    from Solicitacao S
        left join usuario U on (U.UsuID = S.UsuIDResponsavel) 
        left join Status ST on S.SolStatus = ST.CodStatus
        left join Log L on L.LogSolID = s.SolID and (l.LOGDESCRICAO like '%1057%' or l.LOGDESCRICAO like '%3343%')
    where
        S.proid in (2)
        and S.UsuIDResponsavel in (1776)
        and s.SolStatus <> 9
        and convert(date,s.soldata) between '01-01-2018' and getdate()--and s.SolID = 65513
) as X
group by MesID, Mes, Ano
```

Comment: ôpa @W.Faustino, ocorreu a seguinte mensagem na sua primeira query: "A coluna 'Solicitacao.SolData' é inválida na lista de seleção porque não está contida em uma função de agregação nem na cláusula GROUP BY." . E na segunda query também ocorreu o mesmo erro.

Comment: Acho que estamos perto então! O SolData está no GROUP BY! Então, temos que passar para a FUNNTION a data inteira!

Comment: Só mais uma pergunta! A função recebe o que no primeiro parâmetro?

Comment: Editei a resposta, tenta sem a linha do primeiro GROUP BY

Comment: a função recebe as horas uteis entre um certo período, onde nesse caso é entre a data de abertura (s.soldata) e data mínima do log(l.logdata).